# save data to another array, memory management, Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

My purpose: making an API call to a server, and getting back from them is an array of data named `dataArr` and I want to store these data to another array for later need.

What I am doing so far is

`myClass.h`:

```
@propery ( nonatomic, retain ) NSArray *dataList;
```

`myClass.m`:

```
@implementation myClass
-(void)receivedData:(NSArray*) dataArr {
    // ???
}
```

To fill in at line 3, I have two options, option A:

```
dataList = dataArr;
```

or option B:

```
[dataList release];
[dataArr retain];
dataList = dataArr;
```

I think option A is the right way to do it because `dataList` is declared as `retain` in the header file. Therefore, the setter will make sure to release a current array (`dataList`) and  reain a received array (`dataArr`) as well

I just want to double check that I am on the right path.

Please correct me if I have just made a mistake in the middle. Thanks
Any comments are welcomed.

Comment: you must use self.dataList to invoke the property setter

Comment: I've said it before and I'll say it again...I'm SO GLAD that my team decided to move to ARC.  You spend more time writing code and less time worrying about forgetting a retain/release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dataList = [dataArr];
```

this is not valid Objecitve-C. If you wanted to write

```
dataList = dataArr;
```

that's still a no-go, as you're acessing the instance variable directly, not through the property setter, that is, your array won't be retained and it will badly crash.

```
[dataList release];
[dataArr retain];
dataList = dataArr;
```

is wrong again. If `dataList` was the same as `dataArr`, and the reference of the object (`self`) was the last reference to it, then it would get deallocated, breaking the following `retain` message, and most likely crashing again.

If you have a property setter (which you have), simply write

```
self.dataList = dataArr;
```

this will retain the array correctly. By the way, the implementation of the setter is something like your last method, but it checks either for inequality:

```
- (void)setDataList:(NSArray *)dl
{
    if (dataList != dl)
    {
        [dataList release];
        dataList = [dl retain];
    }
}
```

or pre-`retain`s the object to be set:

```
- (void)setDataList:(NSArray *)dl
{
    [dl retain];
    [dataList release];
    dataList = dl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add @synthesize dataList; so the compiler can generate the default setter

then in line 4 add:

```
self.dataList = dataArr;
```

The default setter will take charge of releasing and retaining in a correct manner